# pcre order of precedence in capture group?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

I have a regex that is intended to catch phone numbers in strings:

`[1.-][\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}[\s]?(.[or]?.[1.-][\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}[\s])?`

In addition to catching standard phone numbers in strings (eg. `1-222-3333`) this expression needs to match strings like `1-800-0000 or 1-234-5678`. [It seemingly works as intended](https://regex101.com/r/qhr4kQ/5).

However PHP's `preg_match` function only seems to be matching on the initial phone number and once it finds that disregards the optional `or` part of the pattern

```
$matches = array();
$string = '1-208-687-4348 or 1-509-892-5779';
preg_match('/[1.-][\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}[\s]?(.[or]?.[1.-][\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}[\s])?/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches); // matches[0] => 1-208-687-4348
```

Is my regex missing something? Do I have to specify an order of precedence for the capture group?

Comment: `[or]?` is not `or` that is `o`, or `r` but neither are required because of the `?`. Both numbers fall into the first match which you aren't capturing, use `preg_match_all` and both numbers will be in the `0` group.

Comment: Change `preg_match` with `preg_match_all`. Also, most probably you need to fix the pattern as, say, [`[1.-][\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}(\s+or\s+[1.-][\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}(?!\S))?`](https://regex101.com/r/qhr4kQ/6)